# Probability Of People Visiting Pubs

Tags: probability

> 5 people went out to pubs. everyone individually choose a pub randomly from 10 pubs available.
>   What is the probability that at "Pub1" "Pub2" came at least one person?

$|\Omega|=10^5$

How can I look at this question from set point of view? (e.g $(A_1 \cap A_2)\cup(A_3\cup A_4 \cup A_5)$)

What is the problem with the following answer $\frac{5*4*10^3}{10^5}$?

Comment: @Gary. right sorry. edited

Comment: But it also matters the reason why you came up with the answer, then it is easier to tell if you made a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To frame things your way, let $A_i$ be the event of having someone visit bar number $i$. We want to count $$|A_1|+|A_2|- |A_1 \cap A_2| $$ , i.e., this is the number of ways we can have someone visit bar1 or bar2 , but not both. To get the total, we substract this from the total number of events

We have , for $A_1$:
There are $5$ choices for a person visiting bar1. Then there are $10^4$ ways for the remaining $4$ people to visit the $10$ bars, for a total of $5.10^4=50000$ ways.

For $A_2$: Same thing: we choose a person in $5$ ways to visit bar $2$, and then the remaining $4$ people can visit the remaining bars in $10^4$ ways, for a total of $5.10^4 =50000$ ways.

For $A_1 \cap A_2. $ This is the number of ways of having at least one person in each bar. We can choose in $5C2$ ways the $2$ people so that there is one person in each of bar1, bar2. Then there are $3$ people left, who can choose the remaining $10$ bars in $10^3$ ways, for a total of $5C2. 10^3= 10^4=10000$ ways.

So the total is $50000+50000-10000=90000$ ways.

So the probability is $\frac {10^5-90000}{10^5}=0.1=10$%

Comment: How can we multiple 5 choices for a person and then $10^4$ others visit ing the 10 bars?

I mean we first count people (5) and then count bars (10)

Comment: @gbox: For each of the 5 people , there are 4 left , and these 4 can visit the remaining bars in $10^4$ ways. Let the 5 people be $A,B,C,D,E$. We have 5 choices for the person at bar1: $A,B,C,D,E$. Once we make a choice, say $A$, then $B,C,D,E$ can visit the remaining bars in $10^4$ ways.

Comment: I think I understand it better this way: one pearson is going to Bar1 so we have $10^4$ ways, now we have to choose which person out of the 5 will go to Bar1, so we have ${5\choose 1}*10^4$

Comment: OK, that works too; the best way of understanding it is the one that works well for you.

Answer (score 0):

What is the probability it didn't happen?

It is equal to the probability at least one of the two bars where empty. Let $A$ be the set of outcomes in which pub $1$ is empty and $B$ the set of outcomes in which pub $2$ is empty. We want:

$P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$.

What is $P(A)$?

There are $9^5$ ways in which bar $1$ is empty.

What is $P(B)$? there are $9^5$ ways in which bar $2$ is empty.

What is $P(A\cap B)$?

There are $8^5$ ways in which both are empty.

Hence the probability is $\frac{9^5+9^5-8^5}{10^5}=\frac{85330}{10^5}$.

The probability we are looking for is therefore $\frac{100000-85330}{10^5}=\frac{14670}{100000}=0.14670$

Comment: What did I had to take into account if I would not do the complement?

Comment: It gets messy, this is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

P( choosing at least one to pub1,pub2) =1- p( no one choosing pub1, pub2)

- both pubs are not chooses so remaining 8 pubs are chooses by 5 persons randomly in 8^5 ways
- total pubs 10 chosen by 5 people in 10^5 ways

So probability

P=1- [8^5/10^5]

P=1-[32,768/ 100,000]
P=0.67232
Answer

Comment: I think the OP meant having _at least_ one person in each. So you may have one person in pub1 , but no one in pub2.